# How to get all images fullscreen?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I would like to if there is a way to have all images fullscreen.

The only image that resize with the brower is the background image. The rest of the images are images that fade in and out when you hover a list item.

```
body {
background: black;
width:100%;
height: 100%;
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
}
ul {
list-style:none;
background-color:#00F
}
div {
position:absolute;
z-index:0;
top:0;
left:0;
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
width:100%;
height:100%;
background: url(images/01.jpg);
}
container {
position:absolute;
z-index:1;
left:0;
right:0;
width:270px;
margin:0 0 0 10px;
}

<div id="content">
  <div id="div"></div>
  <div id="container">
    <ul>
      <li id="first">test</li>
      <li id="second">test</li>
      <li id="third">test</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

The images that fade in if you hover the list items are the images that also need te resize. The replace the background by jQuery.

I hope somebody can help me.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Do you want to change the background image? Or to change another image that is somewhere else?

Comment: The background images are already changing by jQuery. But the background images that change by jQuery don't resize.

Answer (score 0):

If I well understand your question,

add to the CSS div style:

```
background-size: cover;
```

(or `background-size: contain;` depending on what you want exactly)